# Difference between beta reduction and single step beta reduction?

Tags: beta, lambda-calculus, reduction

I went through numerous online sources on lambda calculus searching for the difference between beta reduction and single step beta reduction. But all that I know till now is that beta reduction is defined as :

```
(/x.L)M --> {M/x}L
```

and following definition of 1 step beta reduction:
[image]

Can someone please clear the difference between  these two things with some example.They seem to be equivalent to me. Also then there is n step beta reduction which I understood it as being inductively applied 1 step beta reduction. But as the difference between beta reduction and single step beta reduction is not clear, I feel helpless. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think that beta reduction can designate both single and multi step beta reductions.

I can say that beta reduction can yield   `/z.a`  from `(/x./y./z.x) a b`, but I cannot say that a single step beta reduction can do that.

The rest of what you said is correct.